# Passing a property from a parent to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do apologize in advance if such question have been asked before, I have a component that consist of child components , but then i found out that i need to refer to one of the property that parent component have {type} , is there a way i can access type in MetaInfoDocViewer ?

I tried creating a state in YearlyTaxStatement and passing that state to `metaDocViewer: <MetaInfoDocViewer type={this.state.type}/>` but the value is undefined

```
export default class YearlyTaxStatementOverview extends React.Component {

render() {
    return <GeneralDocPresenter type={'income'}
                                fetchMetaDocs={() => getMetaInfoByType('income-tax')}
                                loadDocument={(id) => getYearTaxStatement(id)}
                                eventManager={new EventManager()}
                                settings={{
                                    columnSize: 3
                                }}
                                childComponents={{
                                    metaDocViewer: MetaInfoDocViewer,
                                    metaView: MetaInfoView
                                }}
    />
}


class MetaInfoDocViewer extends React.Component {

state = {
   send: false
};

render() {
    const sendModal = <SendModal type={i need type here } onClose={() => {this.setState({send: false})}}
                                 docIds={this.props.selectedDocsStore.selectedDocs}/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not really able to follow your code. But the answer is that you can send it as a props.

Or if you have to use it in several places, you can save it in a Redux Store and then that state is reachable from every component where you connect it.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    type: state.type
  };
};

    .
    .
    .
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(COMPONENT NAME);
```